# Find every possible distribution of the x elements considering a constraint on one of them

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

Considering a number `r` of triplets `{ a, c, i }`

I'd like to know which procedure / math field should I use to calculate every possible triplet combination in `r` knowing that `a` must be `>= 1`

Real life example: 
Give a certain amount of adults (`a`), children (`c`) and infants (`i`), I'd like to calculate every possible distribution of people in a specific amount of rooms (`r`) knowing that every room should at least have an adult (`a >= 1`) in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Methodology**

This is a classic "balls and urns" problem. You have $r$ urns, and $a$ adults. (We'll do the adults first). You first distribute $r$ of the adults, one into each room. You can then think of the problem as having $a-r$ adults and $a$ rooms in which to place them. This is now a classic "[stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)" question. (In fact, the wikipedia link states the general form for both having at least $1$ adult in each room, and having no restriction).

You then have the same idea problem for the children and the infants.

Then, at the end of the day, you multiply these numbers together, just like when you have $2$ choices of dessert, main course, and appetizer, you have $2\cdot 2\cdot 2 = 8$ total possibilities.

Comment: Uhm I just realized that my question is a bit ambiguos, what I'd like to calculate is not the number of combinations, but the combinations itself.
Is there a way to get to that result?